# Using Power Automate to Export Outlook .xlsx Attachment to SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, flow, attachments, power-automate

I'm in the middle of setting up an automated flow using Microsoft Power Automate and I have some questions. I'm seeking to extract an .xlsx file from an Outlook email attachment and have the data from the attachment imported into a SharePoint master list.

I have the SharePoint master list columns set up to match the fields in the attachment.

The fields in the attachment are dynamic,some of the fields in the attachment are: Name, Priority, Open Date, Resolve Date, Description, etc. So there are a few different elements besides strings.

I would like to have the attachment data added to the SharePoint master list which will be updated each time the attachment is sent with new information.

To my knowledge, I believe the attachment needs to be saved somewhere before the data can be extracted to populate the SharePoint list; however, I'm not sure where to start with this flow. I've tried a few different runs and one of them was successful; however, my data from the attachment was not output anywhere. If anyone has some suggestions I'd really appreciate the help.

Ryan

Updated:
[image]
[image]

First image: The email arrives with the attachment with a trigger that sends it to a specified mailbox, the file is created in SharePoint with the attachment (name/content) "List rows present in table" - The Location is the general SharePoint site and the document library is the folder path where the document is stored. The file is the dynamic ID from the original SharePoint "create file" action. Lastly, the table "export (1)" is the same table name in the attachment that I'm trying to extract data from.

Second image: I'm applying the value from the "list rows present in table" action and creating an item in SharePoint at the list that I already have populated with the same fields as the attachment. Ex. My SharePoint list has Open time, Service Recipient and so on.

Where I'm running into issues is that nothing is being exported into my SharePoint list on the last "create item" step and I'm not sure why. The attachment is being extracted from the email and a file is created in SharePoint using the "create file" action, I just can't figure out how to get that data into my SharePoint list.

Answer (score 0):

We could use "when a new email arrives" with specific folder in outlook to trigger the flow.

I don't think we can get the metadata in attachments dynamically.

Below article about using Flow to organize and process email attachments for your reference:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Community-Blog/Use-Flow-To-Organize-and-Process-Email-Attachments/ba-p/182188

Comment: Thank you, I do already have a similar flow established; however my data will be dynamic and I don't want to update the list or overwrite any existing data. Essentially, I'll have a weekly email come in with an attachment that I need to extract data from and place it into a master SharePoint list. I will update my original post with screenshots of what I have thus far.